# ref.clientHeight is returning a different value than expected

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I am building a Next.js component where I'm using a div ref to "pull up" a div up onto another with the use of negative margins.

The top vid has a video child; this is the minimal code:

```
export const Project: FC<Props> = ({ videoUrl, imageUrl }) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>(0);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { width } = useWindowSize();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref?.current?.clientHeight) {
      setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
    }
  }, [width, ref?.current?.clientHeight]);

  // prints 450
  console.log("current clientHeight: ", ref?.current?.offsetHeight);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Column is a simple css-grid item div */}
      <Column>
        <div ref={ref}>
            <video style={{width: "100%" }}>
                <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
      </Column>
      <Column mt={-height + 64}>
         <img src={imageUrl} />
      </Column>
    </>
  );
};
```

The issue that I'm having is that the browser renders the video and the containing column at around 500, but `clientHeight` is printed at 450.

This difference is not enabling me to implement the design as intended...

Resizing the window will often produce the desired effect, but it never happens on first render (tried on Chrome and Safari for MacOS)

Any ideas as to what could be happening, and how to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: By looking at the example code, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish; however, perhaps this [How to Stack Elements in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-stack-elements-in-css/) might help. If this doesn't help, please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried setting ref.current on component did mount?